# Best way to handle hash reponse from soap

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, soap, hash

I need to get some information from a delivery company who is using soap to get the list of delivery points. I finished my classes to call and execute the soap request and this is the format of the response :

```
{
:error_message=> "Code retour OK", 
:liste_point_retrait =>
[
    {
        :horaires_ouverture_dimanche => "00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00", 
        :poids_maxi => "20000", 
        :conges_partiel => false, 
        :horaires_ouverture_vendredi => "09:00-12:00 14:30-18:00", 
        :acces_personne_mobilite_reduite => false, 
        :horaires_ouverture_jeudi => "09:00-12:00 14:30-17:30", 
        :nom => "BUREAU DE POSTE SAINT LEU D ESSERENT BP"
    }, 
    {
        :horaires_ouverture_dimanche => "00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00", 
        :poids_maxi => "20000", 
        :conges_partiel => false, 
        :horaires_ouverture_vendredi => "09:00-12:00 14:00- 17:00", 
        :acces_personne_mobilite_reduite => true, 
        :horaires_ouverture_jeudi => "09:00-12:00 14:00-17:00", 
        :nom => "BUREAU DE POSTE PRECY SUR OISE BP"
    }, 
    {
        :horaires_ouverture_dimanche => "00:00-00:00 00:00-00:00", 
        :poids_maxi=> "20000",  
        :conges_partiel => false, 
        :horaires_ouverture_vendredi => "08:30-12:00 14:30-17:00",
        :acces_personne_mobilite_reduite => false, 
        :horaires_ouverture_jeudi => "08:30-12:00 14:30-17:00", 
        :nom => "BUREAU DE POSTE SAINT MAXIMIN BP"
    }
], 
:error_code=> "0", 
:qualite_reponse=> "1", 
:ws_request_id => "01587849465dc81b5eb19996cdd5d1cae4ead7766316f12e4fbfa6e86037caae"
}
```

The problem now is that I don't like the way I currently get the information to display it in my views, for example if @points contains this hash I use this in my code:

```
<% @points[:liste_point_retrait].each do |point| %>
  <%= point[:nom] %>
<% end %>
```

Is there a better way to handle this response? I would like to have the possibilty to do something like this :

```
<% @points.each do |point| %>
   <%= point.name %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: What would you want your last segment to do? Ruby's Hash has an `each`, it passes the key as the first argument to the block and the value as the second. Anyway, what's wrong with the first approach? Or do you want an object representing your data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the data inside of the `:liste_point_retrait` key then only use that key?:

```
@points = @points[:liste_point_retrait]
```

Then you can continue to traverse this with

```
<% @points.each do |point| %>
  <%= point[:nom] %>
<% end %>
```

If you would rather use `point.nom` over `point[:nom]` then you can create an `OpenStruct` from each Hash element. That is:

```
@points.map! { |p| OpenStruct.new(p)
```

I see you have `name` vs `nom` in your example and I'm not sure if that's intentional or not. If so, you need to translate all of these keys yourself.